# AMD Geode LX linux : how to instruct driver to enable flat panel?

Tags: drivers, linux-kernel

*Platform : PC/104 with AMD Geode LX CPU with integrated graphics. Buildroot framework, kernel 4.18.10.*

I am building a custom Linux system with Buildroot. Since I compiled the Geode LX frame buffer driver in the kernel (lxfb), I get a black screen on the flat panel (800x600 LCD), but the VGA output works.

It seems like the driver needs some input, but I can't figure out how to do it. See last struct : https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/video/geode/geodefb.h?h=linux-4.18.y&id=b5c26f97ec4a17c650055c83cfc1f2ee6d8818eb

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid me. The answer was in the driver documentation here : https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/fb/lxfb.txt?h=linux-4.18.y

I just need to pass `lxfb.mode_option=800x600@75` to the kernel command line, and voilà !